# findviewbyid - Cannot Resolve

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

This is one of my fragments that I am using in a `navigation drawer`. I need to add a button that when pressed, changes to a text box into different text. I keep getting errors that the `findviewbyid()` int cannot be resolved and such. I could get this working on `MainActivity/activity_main`, but when I use one of the pages of the nav drawer(like `ConnectFragment.java/fragment_connect.xml`), I get errors.

This is the code for just the ConnectFragment alone

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ConnectFragment extends Fragment {
    public ConnectFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }       
}
```

This is the code i want to implement

```
final Button ClassAButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ClassAButton);

ClassAButton.setOnClickListener(
    new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            TextView FeloniesText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.FeloniesText);
            FeloniesText.setText("Button 1 Has been pressed!");
        }
    }
);
```

Code from the XML (relative layout tag here, formatting got messed up)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/ClassAButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/FeloniesText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="107dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also want to add multiple buttons to change the text view to different things, so I would be something like, Class A button prints out hi, Class B Button prints out yes, Class C Button prints out elephant, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :D BTW API 15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this.**

Change this line.

```
final Button ClassAButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ClassAButton);
```

To this.

```
final Button ClassAButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ClassAButton);

TextView FeloniesText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.FeloniesText);
```

**Edit : For text view try this.**

```
ClassAButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view){
                    FeloniesText.setText("Button 1 Has been pressed!");
                }
            }
    );
```

Replace this in your code.

**Edit 2 :**

Replace this full code with your code.

In reference link they have taken Activity and You have take fragment.

```
public class ConnectFragment extends Fragment {

final Button ClassAButton;
TextView FeloniesText;



public ConnectFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false);
    init(rootView);
    return rootView;

}


public void init(View view)
{
    ClassAButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ClassAButton);
    FeloniesText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.FeloniesText);
    ClassAButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view){
                    FeloniesText.setText("Button 1 Has been pressed!");
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, the code works and there is no more error, but upon pressing the button, the app crashes, help?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: nota.outlawsindex, PID: 3236
                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at nota.outlawsindex.ConnectFragment$1.onClick(ConnectFragment.java:33)

Comment: @TyreseBrown Check my edited answer i have updated on click listener.

Comment: Yes, once using the code you have updated, the app still crashes upon pressing the button

Comment: @TyreseBrown Check my edited answer. I have removed text view from on click listener. And defined it to below class button.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'Felonies Text' is the error i am getting from line
FeloniesText.setText("Button 1 Has been pressed!");

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxoG_Y6dvU8#t=300.1785 This is where i referenced this information

Comment: @TyreseBrown Check my EDIT 2 part.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wouldnt have been able to finsih this part of the project without your help,It finally worked I cannot thank you enough :D

Comment: @TyreseBrown Please accept the answer. Mark right for answer and upvote also thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById` is not part of `Fragment`. It's part of `ViewGroup` so instead of

```
(TextView)findViewById(R.id.FeloniesText);
```

you need to

```
(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.FeloniesText);
```

Comment: TextView FeloniesText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.FeloniesText);

 
currently getting error as in: Variable 'root view' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

im getting this error for only this line, not the others